# Wrapped figure using wrapfig package in latex goes below the text

Tags: latex, figure

When I use "'wrapfigure"' in latex document the figure doesn't appear inplace. Instead it appears below the text as shown. What could be the solution for this?

```
\documentclass[18pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{\nolinebreak}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Enrichment analysis:}\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Gene Set Enrichment Analysis (GSEA):\\
~\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{R}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width =0.4\textwidth]{GSEA-homegraphic}
\caption{GSEA process[22]}
\label{gsea}
\end{wrapfigure} 



GSEA is a computational method that determines whether a previously defined set of genes shows statistically significant, concordant differences between two 
biological states (e.g., phenotypes).[22]

Gsea use two types of test statistics: 
                             
- Fisher’s exact test: which is based on gene counts. It is a statistical test used to determine if there are non-random associations between two categorical variables.[23]

- Kolmogorov-Smirnov like test : which computes enrichment based on gene scores 
(representing how differentially expressed a gene is). Genes can be categorized into 
differentially expressed or not differentially expressed genes.[24]
It is a non-parametric test that compares the cumulative distributions of two data sets; i.e. It does not assume that data are sampled from Gaussian distributions (or any other defined distributions). It reports the maximum difference between the two cumulative distributions, and calculates a P value from that and the sample sizes (Fig.10).[25] 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

and the following appears
[image]

Comment: I don't think Wrapfigure will work inside of an itemize or enumerate environment. My suggestion is put the wrapfigure above or below the itemization/enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: keep `wrapfigs` away from list. In your specific case, I would not put this image in a `wrapfig` - instead make it bigger so that the font in the image will match the normal text size and is thus comfortable to read.

Quote from the `wrapfig` documentation

> You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or or immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line (`\par`) in between.